# cakephp: Paginate after doing 2 queries

Tags: php, cakephp, pagination, paginator

How to paginate after doing 2 queries?

I have:

```
   $this->Paginator->settings = array(
                'conditions' => array('Record.status =' => 'published',  
                                              'RecordUser.flagged =' => null, 
                              'Record.category_id =' => $likes
                                ),
                'limit' => 5,
                'order' => array('rate' => 'desc')
            );
```

and I want to do this as well:

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
                'conditions' => array('Record.status =' => 'published',  
                                              'RecordUser.flagged =' => null, 
                              'Record.category_id !=' => $likes
                                ),
                'limit' => 5,
                'order' => array('rate' => 'desc')
            );
```

then merge the results.. 
The problem is the result on 1st query limits to 5 then continues to the 2nd page. I want all results from the 1st query before the result on the 2nd query displays.

How do I do this?
I'm using cakephp 2.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why can't you just make one single query and use the order by?

```
$likes = implode(',', $likes);

$this->YourModel->virtualFields['in_like'] = "IF(Record.category_id IN ($likes), 0, 1)";

$this->Paginator->settings = array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Record.status =' => 'published',  
        'RecordUser.flagged =' => null, 
     ),
     'limit' => 10,
     'order' => array('in_like' => 'asc', 'rate' => 'desc')
);
```

Comment: I need those that are in the $likes to show at the top before the other records (2nd query) show up

Comment: so please explain how is your $like array like

Comment: $likes can contain the values (category_id) from the Category table and it can also contain strings (other $likes not in the Category table)

Comment: so how can category_id be a string? It has to be an id. You have to clean your array from the strings that are not an id.

Comment: Figured it out. strings need single quotes. How can i forget about that? haha. THANKS FOR YOUR HELP! :)